# Rational Quality Manager CLI Adapter not returning attachments during execution

Tags: bash, ibm-jazz, ibm-rational

I have a local bash script that is being executed by RQM through the RQM Command Line Interface Adapter. I want to return some results back into my Test Execution Record as described here:

https://jazz.net/library/article/809

I have a line in the script that should handle this:

```
echo hypervisors=/tmp/hypv.out >> $qm_AttachmentsFile
```

However, when I run the TER I end up with the STDOUT from the script as is normal, and another .err file with the following contents:

```
/home/vance/RQM-scripts/sample1.sh: line 21: $qm_AttachmentsFile: ambiguous redirect
```

[image]

I know that the bash error "ambiguous redirect" is probably due to the qm_AttachmentsFile not existing, but it should!

Any help please?

Comment: does the value for `$qm_AttachmentFile` have a space in it? Or worse yet, shell wild card char (`*,?,[...]`) or syntax char (`&;#$(){}`)? Generally speaking you always want to dbl-quote var names, i.e. `. . . > "$qm_AttachmentFile"`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks shellter, I wondered the same thing on my drive home. When I get back to this on Monday I will dump the environment during runtime and see just what is going on with qm_AttachmentFile.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the script to print the environment out. There is no qm_AttachmentsFile being injected into the environment during runtime:

```
XDG_SESSION_ID=15397
HOSTNAME=**REDACTED**
SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
HISTSIZE=1000
SSH_CLIENT=**REDACTED** 53534 22
OS_REGION_NAME=RegionOne
SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
qm_sourceRC=/home/vance/admin.rc
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/1
USER=vance
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
qm_CustomPropertiesFile=/tmp/QMAdapter2058030468790321214.props
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/vance
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/vance/bin:/home/vance/.local/bin:/home/vance/bin
PWD=/home/vance/RQM-CLI-Adapter
OS_PASSWORD=openstack1
XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
OS_AUTH_URL=http://**REDACTED**:5000/v2.0
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
HOME=/home/vance
SHLVL=3
OS_USERNAME=admin
OS_TENANT_NAME=admin
LOGNAME=vance
SSH_CONNECTION=**REDACTED**
OS_VOLUME_API_VERSION=2
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1022
qm_ExecutionVariablesFile=/tmp/QMAdapter8441414611088888164.vars
_=/usr/bin/env
[{"ID": 1, "Hypervisor Hostname": "**REDACTED**"}, {"ID": 21, "Hypervisor Hostname": "**REDACTED**"}, {"ID": 22, "Hypervisor Hostname": "**REDACTED**"}]
```

There's no qm_AttachmentsFile variable in the environment. After checking versions of both the RQM server and the CLI adapter, I believe I have a back level adapter. I am going to try to upgrade the adapter to the latest version and will report back on my results.